# Automatically deducing the type of bind1st(mem_fun(&my_class::f), this)?

Tags: c++, templates, stl, functional-programming, functor

I would like to pass the `bind1st(mem_fun(&my_class::f), this)` functor to `for_each`. Unfortunately it is very difficult to read so I would like to give it a more readible name like this:

```
(the type I am looking for) meaningful_name = bind1st(mem_fun(&my_class::f), this);

for_each(v.begin(), v.end(), meaningful_name);
```

Is there a simple way to deduce the type of the functor? (I know `mem_fun` saves us a lot of pain exactly for this reason.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This depends on the argument and return types of my_class:f. If the function is

```
T my_class::f(A arg)
```

then you need

```
binder1st<mem_fun1_t<T,my_class,A> > meaningful_name = bind1st(mem_fun(&my_class::f), this);
```

This kind of thing will be nicer with C++0x:

```
auto meaningful_name = bind1st(mem_fun(&my_class::f), this);
```

Comment: Almost: it should be `mem_fun1_t`, not `mem_fun1_1`.

Answer (score 2):

No there is no simple way. The type name will be rather long and even more unreadable. And if you use boost, you don't need to use `BOOST_AUTO`, because you can just use `boost::bind` and have it readable, without a need for a local.

```
for_each(v.begin(), v.end(), boost::bind(&my_class::f, this));
```